# Filtering top command output

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, awk, top

I'm running a Mac and want to filter the output of the `top` command for a particular process such that only the PID, COMMAND and %CPU columns are displayed.

After getting the PID of the process, I run:

```
top -pid 1234
```

However this displays more than 15 columns for that process. Can I pipe the output of 'the command in to awk and display only the:

```
PID COMMAND %CPU
```

columns?

I don't want to store the output in a text file and then process it. I'm interested in monitoring the process in real time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
top -pid 3907 -stats "pid,command,cpu"
```

- `-pid 3907`: your process ID
- `-stats pid,command,cpu`: only show process ID, name and CPU%

No need to run `awk` on the output.

---

If you want to post-process the output, use `-l 0` to run in *logging* mode (0 means indefinitely, everything else limits number of samples). Output will look like this (two repetitions):

```
Processes: 72 total, 3 running, 1 stuck, 68 sleeping, 326 threads 
2011/05/10 19:15:13
Load Avg: 0.14, 0.14, 0.09 
CPU usage: 20.0% user, 26.66% sys, 53.33% idle 
SharedLibs: 5304K resident, 5208K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 16345 total, 1048M resident, 54M private, 338M shared.
PhysMem: 726M wired, 1802M active, 687M inactive, 3215M used, 750M free.
VM: 169G vsize, 1036M framework vsize, 5261732(0) pageins, 552476(0) pageouts.
Networks: packets: 46747406/52G in, 32528901/3715M out.
Disks: 9452898/244G read, 11226269/293G written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU
3907  WindowServer 0.0 
Processes: 72 total, 3 running, 1 stuck, 68 sleeping, 326 threads 
2011/05/10 19:15:14
Load Avg: 0.13, 0.14, 0.09 
CPU usage: 0.95% user, 1.90% sys, 97.14% idle 
SharedLibs: 5304K resident, 5208K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 16346 total, 906M resident, 54M private, 386M shared.
PhysMem: 726M wired, 1802M active, 687M inactive, 3215M used, 751M free.
VM: 169G vsize, 1036M framework vsize, 5261732(0) pageins, 552476(0) pageouts.
Networks: packets: 46747406/52G in, 32528901/3715M out.
Disks: 9452898/244G read, 11226269/293G written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU
3907  WindowServer 2.7
```

Use `awk` or a similar tool to only display every 13th line (as these lines contain the values in that example):

```
$ top -l 0 -pid 3907 -stats pid,command,cpu | awk 'NR%13==0'
3907  WindowServer 0.0 
3907  WindowServer 1.3 
3907  WindowServer 2.2
```

Comment: `# top -p1 -stats "pid,command,cpu"  top: unknown option 't'`

Comment: @AstraSerg Works for me. Note that this is a Mac OS question, which has a different `top` than Linux.

Answer (score 6):

This certainly can be done and I'm going to explain how I would do it. I'm not pretending this is an optimal approach, but it does the job. I am using Linux (and bash shell), so the default behavior of my top may be slightly different. Thus you may need to tune this mini-howto for your particular scenario.

1. Just run **top**, without any arguments:

   `$ top`

   Here is the header and a relevant line from my output:

   `PID   USER  PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM  TIME+    COMMAND`

   `2569  user  20   0  339m  86m  10m S  7.8  6.9  6:42.99  java`

   I have picked up a process that stays in memory for some time and actually consumes CPU, I will be using it as test process for reaching the final goal.
2. By default, top runs in interactive mode. This doesn't suit me, I want to capture the relevant data and print it. I will handle the task of displaying the data interactively after that. Relevant quotes from top manpage:

   > -b : Batch mode operation
   >        Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending
   >        output from top to other programs or  to  a  file.   In  this
   >        mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
   >        limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option  or  until
   >        killed.
   >
   > -n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
   >        Specifies  the  maximum  number of iterations, or frames, top
   >        should produce before ending.

   This is the adjusted top command that prints output only once, then exits:

   `$ top -b -n 1`
3. I know the PID I want to watch, so I'll add one more restriction to top, so it prints data only about that process:

   `$ top -b -n 1 -p 2569`
4. Even in batch mode, top still prints a header, containing misc system-wide stats like uptime, free memory/swap etc. I don't need this. All I need is only one line - the one that contains data about my process, so I'll cut it from the whole output like this:

   `$ top -b -n 1 -p 2569 | tail -n 2 | head -n 1`

   As you can see, I've got the second line from 1.
5. I'll pipe this line to awk to extract only the columns I need:

   `$ top -b -n 1 -p 2569 | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $12, $9}'`
6. Until now, I've been doing these manipulations in command line, now it's the moment to add some persistence and flexibility to our hardcoded particular case. I am moving the whole line into a simple shell script. I'll call it **3top**, the name is emphasized because it will be used later:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `top -b -n 1 -p 2569 | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $12, $9}'`
7. The PID number is hardcoded, here's how to make the script to accept it as command line argument:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `top -b -n 1 -p "$1" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $12, $9}'`

   To make 3top display stats about PID 2569, it must be called like this:

   `$ ./3top 2569`
8. I also want percentage displayed after CPU load, so I'm tuning my 3top script like this:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `out=$(top -b -n 1 -p "$1" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $12, $9}')`

   `echo "$out%"`

   I have redirected the whole output of a chain of commands (connected through pipes) into a variable. Then I just print it using echo and add a '%' at the end, since CPU load is the last field
9. At this point I have a batch script that accepts a PID as argument and prints stats once. Want real time monitoring instead? It's easy, because **watch** can do it! Run the script like this:

   `$ watch -n 1 3top 2569`

   It will do real time monitoring by running 3top once per second.

Comment: The user is on OS X and has no Gnu `top`. *invalid option or syntax: -b*. No idea why this was repeatedly upvoted.

Comment: Gnu `top` (in `procps`) cannot be installed using Homebrew, MacPorts or Fink and cannot be compiled from source using either `make` or `cc top.c`.

Answer (score 2):

The `top` display format is customizable, but there is not a way to specify display options at the command line. If you are inventive, however, you can probably do what you need by cleverly manipulating the `~/.toprc` file.

Assuming you have not already customized the display of `top` (and do not have a `~/.toprc` file):

1. Launch `top`.
2. Press <kbd>f</kbd> to enter field select mode.
3. For each field that has an `*` next to it that you do not want, press the corresponding letter to deselect that field. For example, press <kbd>e</kbd> to deselect the `User Name` field. When you are done, you should only have an `*` next to `Process Id`, `CPU usage`, and `Command name/line`.
4. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to return to the main window.
5. Press <kbd>W</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) to save the current layout to your `~/.toprc` file.
6. Quit `top`, then relaunch to verify that your settings are saved.
7. When you want to return to the default layout, rename `~/.toprc` to something like `~/min.toprc` before launching `top`. When you want to switch to the minimal layout, rename `~/min.toprc` back to `~/.toprc` before launching `top`.

This file renaming and launching `top` can probably be worked into a simple shell script by someone with an ounce more experience and knowledge than me. You will need special consideration if your regular `top` layout has already been customized.

Comment: Is it possible to add a filter (even if manually) to `.toprc`? I like to add the filter `RUID>999` at startup.